# Cannot read property 'lists' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, droppable, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd

I am trying to create a web application that mimics trello. I keep getting this error and im not sure how to fix it. The code works fine in another project but not when i try and add it to this new project. ALL dependencies are updated. I am running it on google chrome. I read it might be a problem with chrome?

[This is the error that I am receiving on my browser. There are no errors in my IDE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOgn0.png)

[This is the code that is producing this error. The code works fine in another IDE but once I try to integrate the component into my new app it crashes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yalYs.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please avoid posting pictures of the issue and instead descripe it or paste the shown code in a stack snippet. The question should be understandable even when the url of the image has vanished. The best way to show the issue is with a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are getting array in list key in "board" Props and try to use optional Channing

```
{
  boar?.list?.map(..)
}
```

Your board props is undefined that's why you're getting this error.

Comment: That works to fix the error but then the rest of the code isn't functioning properly.